# svn help to get all history

Tags: svn, changelog

Summary: I want to know that how can I get all the change log from svn.

I know about SVN LOG URL, but it does not give me detail that what 
files were changed in that commit. It just gives me commit message.

I want to know that what files were affected with each commit.

Is there any way to get it for all svn commits?

Thanks

p.s: I tried svn diff too but it is just for 2 revisions and I have thousands
revisions !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

just use -v on log

```
svn log <url> -v
```

#### oh yea, and...

to specify revision, use -r ... so:

```
svn log <url> -r <rev#> -v
```

for a revision range, use `<firstRev#>:<lastRev#>` like:

```
svn log <url> -r 1:5 -v
```

Comment: yeah I tried this as well but it is not showing any file name that was changed for each revision :(

Comment: @user431276: it's not showing the `M <filepath>` list using the above command?  What svn version are you using?

Comment: @user431276: are you sure files were actually changed for those revisions? not propsets or whatnot?

Comment: or you could try --verbose rather than -v... other than that I have no idea why it wouldn't be printing changelists.  I just did the above commands on mine and they all printed the files involved in each committ.

Comment: i used --verbose and it didn't work but -v worked for me. any idea why is this?

Comment: @user431276: are you sure you put both dashes in front of verbose, like `--verbose` instead of `-verbose`?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a regular expression that I use in notepad++ for grabbing the commits by a particular user.

```
^r[0-9]+\ \|\ user\.name.*$[^[^-]*$]*
```